# I have got the "Authorization code" for my app. But how can I use it to post in the blogger using gdata-python-client?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, blogger, gdata-api, gdata-python-client

I am using gdata-pyton-client.
I have got the "Authorization code" for my app. But now what? How can I use it to post in the blogger?

I used the following code and get eh Authorization code,

> ```
> CLIENT_ID = 'my-client-id'
> CLIENT_SECRET = 'my-secret'
>
> SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger']  
> USER_AGENT = 'my-app'
>
> token = gdata.gauth.OAuth2Token(
>                                 client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, scope=' '.join(SCOPES),
>                                 user_agent=USER_AGENT)
>
> print token.generate_authorize_url(redirect_url='urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob')
> print token.get_access_token(TOKEN-THAT-I-GOT-FROM-ABOVE-URL)
> ```

But now how do I use it?

How can I authorize the blogger, for posting it to the blogger?
I have been using this example for my testing purpose:
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/blogger/BloggerExampleV1.py

But this is using email & password for login. How can I use the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below solution.

Please ensure that all below imports are there.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenRefreshError
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run
```

Setup your client_secrets.JSON like this

setup client_secrets.json like

```
{
  "web": {
    "client_id": "[[INSERT CLIENT ID HERE]]",
    "client_secret": "[[INSERT CLIENT SECRET HERE]]",
    "redirect_uris": [],
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
  }
}
```

For future reference you can store the Credentials in a file `blogger.dat` for faster processing

```
FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(Path_to_client_secrets.json,scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger',message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

storage = Storage('blogger.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
```

Once the Credentials are all setup. its time to post! so we Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it with our good Credentials.

```
http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

service = build("blogger", "v2", http=http)
```

Once done we build the blog body and post

```
try:
    body = {
        "kind": "blogger#post",
        "id": "6814573853229626501",
        "title": "posted via python",
        "content":"<div>hello world test</div>"
        }

    request = service.posts().insert(your_blogId_ID,body)

    response = request.execute()
    print response

  except AccessTokenRefreshError:
    print ("The credentials have been revoked or expired, please re-run the application to re-authorize")
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

See [this documentation page](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/wiki/HTTPRequestRefactoring) instructing you how to use your tokens, particularly the example at the end:

```
# Find a token to set the Authorization header as the request is being made
token = self.token_store.find_token(url)
# Tell the token to perform the request using the http_client object
# By default, the http_client is an instance of atom.http.HttpClient which uses httplib to         make requests
token.perform_request(self.http_client, 'GET', url, data=None, headers)
```

Comment: jknupp, thanks for this example, but I am very new to the Python Programming and this is my first experience with the GData also. I still didn't understand properly how to authorize the client so that it can post to blogger...